# Два cписка объединить в словарь с обработкой

Tags: python, словари, список

Есть два списка:

```py
unique_set2 = ['1111', '1111', '1231', '1211', '1111', '1231', '1001', '1001', '1001', '1001', '1111', '1231', '1231', '1001', '1001', '1111', '1505', '1231', '1231', '1001', '1001', '1231', '1211', '1212']

count = [111, 3, 13, 111, 9, 5, 17, 10, 13, 3, 16, 4, 16, 11, 18, 12, 14, 4, 3, 2, 14, 14, 10, 10]
```

Надо объединить их в словарь с обработкой. Если ключ уже есть, то значение прибавлять к имеющемуся:

```py
d = {}

for i, j in zip(unique_set2, count):
  if i in d:
    прибавлять значение j к имеющемуся
  else:
    добавить новую пару в словарь
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в лоб так:

```
res = dict()

for first, second in zip(unique_set2, count):
    if first in res:
        res[first] += second
    else:
        res[first] = second

print(res)
```

чуть более короткое решение:

```
res = dict()

for first, second in zip(unique_set2, count):
    res[first] = res.get(first, 0) + second
```

P.S.

чтобы подсчитать среднее - нужно модифицировать код на такой:

```
res = dict()

for first, second in zip(unique_set2, count):
    res[first] = res.get(first, []) + [second]

for key in res:
    res[key] = sum(res[key]) / len(res[key])

print(res)
```

или такой:

```
res = dict()
counts = dict()

for first, second in zip(unique_set2, count):
    res[first] = res.get(first, 0) + second
    counts[first] = counts.get(first, 0) + 1

for key in res:
    res[key] /= counts[key]
```

Comment: А как посчитать среднее значение(second) то есть сумма / на кол-во раз встретившееся?
Например 1111 встречается 5 раз значит сумму делим на 5

Comment: в общем да - добавил код для примера

Answer (score 0):

вариант похожий на уже предложенные с циклом:

```
res = dict.fromkeys(unique_set2, 0)
for i in range(len(count)):
    res[unique_set2[i]] += count[i]
```

с использованием библиотеки pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame({'set':unique_set2,'count':count}).groupby('set')['count'].sum().to_dict()
```

если во втором варианте заменить `sum` на `mean` то получите средние значения